# Countdown timer cancel is not working

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, timer, countdowntimer

This has been asked many times, but i am still unsure how to fix it,

I have created a class, that is extending from `CountDownTimer`.

> public  class CounterClass extends CountDownTimer

This class is singleton so 3 activities are using it, and timer value is same for all of them; which is fine.

but when user press back button, from `activity 1`, i want timer value to reset.

This is what i am doing to cancel timer.

```
   CounterClass.getInstance().cancel();

   CounterClass.elapsedTime = -1;
```

**Class File**

```
public  class CounterClass extends CountDownTimer {

    static CounterClass  instance;

    public static CounterClass getInstance(){
        if(instance == null) {
            instance = new CounterClass(millisInFutureConitunationValue, 1);
        }

        return instance;
    }


    public static CounterClass getInstance(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval){
        instance = new CounterClass(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        return instance;
    }

    private CounterClass(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super((elapsedTime < 0)?millisInFuture:elapsedTime, countDownInterval);
    }


    public void setContext(Context context){
        this.context= context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        long millis= millisUntilFinished;
        elapsedTime = millisUntilFinished;

        String hms= String.format("%02d:%02d",
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes( millisUntilFinished),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) -
                        TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished)));

        tvTimer.setText(hms);
    }
```

Comment: see this link https://gist.github.com/Gautier/737759